# Is it possible to get dates of next monday and sunday in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I need to be able to get dates of the next week's Monday and Sunday for a SQL query. Is there a function that would return those dates?

Comment: If you need it in SQL how the question is related to VB.NET?

Comment: For a SQL query, it will display bookings in a data grid view.

Comment: Do you mean the Sunday and the Monday on the day after that, or the Monday and then the Sunday six days after that?

Comment: Monday and six days after that sorry for not making it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly get the result also in SQL, however, in VB.NET it's easy:

```
Dim today = Date.Today
Dim daysUntilNextSunday As Int32 = (DayOfWeek.Sunday - today.DayOfWeek + 7) Mod 7
Dim nextSunday = today.AddDays(daysUntilNextSunday)
```

The same with `DayOfWeek.Monday`

Comment: Would this work even if today wasn't Tuesday?

Comment: `(DayOfWeek.Sunday - today.DayOfWeek + 7)` can be simplified to `7 - Today.DayOfWeek` (because `DayOfWeek.Sunday == 0`). And `Mod 7` should probably be dropped assuming that we always want Sunday of _next_ week even if today is Sunday. See my deleted answer below.

Comment: @41686d6564 when I test the code it returns the Sunday of this week (16/05/2021) instead of the next one would there be a solution to this?

Comment: @MiloszLaksa Sorry, where I am from, Sunday _is_ next week so I always forget. If your week starts on Monday, you can just add 7 to `daysUntilNextSunday`. In that case, you _will_ need the `Mod 7` part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```vb
Private Function EveryDayByDate(day As DayOfWeek) As IEnumerable(Of DateTime)
    Dim rightNow = DateTime.Now
    Dim lastOfNextMonth = New DateTime(rightNow.Year, rightNow.Month, 1).AddMonths(2).AddDays(-1)
    Return Enumerable.Range(1, lastOfNextMonth.Day).Select(Function(counter) New DateTime(rightNow.Year, lastOfNextMonth.Month, counter)).Where(Function(d) d.DayOfWeek = day)
End Function
```

The way that it works is it gets every day in next month, checks if it falls on a given day of the week. By doing it like this, we don't need to worry about things like leap years.

Usage would be:

```vb
Dim mondays = EveryDayByDate(DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KDCkRu

Comment: To get the number of days in a month, you can use the [DateTime.DaysInMonth(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.daysinmonth).